# HTML email signature with variables populated from database

Tags: html, database

Not sure how to even ask this, but I'm at a stopping point and cannot go further. I am not a programmer and I only dabble in code infrequently, but I would appreciate any help.

Basically, I have written HTML for standardizing an email signature for myself and fellow educators. What I would like to do is create a form (Google Form) that allows them to input the variables such as name, title, email, and phone numbers in the HTML code...then have it spit back the rendered HTML on the same page for them to copy and then paste into the email signature field of their mail client. Not to go in to too much detail, but AD or LDAP distribution is not an option for us right now, so this seems like a solution that may help all parties...if we can get it going.

What I would ideally want is to have the one webpage where let's say the left half of the page is the form and the right side is what renders when they submit.

How can I start to go about this? Here is the static code I have already:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>


<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 
0px; padding-right: 0px;">
<span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: Garamond; font-
size: 13pt; font-weight: bold">James McCrary</span><br>
<span style="text-align: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; color: 
#606060; font-family: Garamond; font-weight: normal; font-size: 
10pt;">Academic Technology Coordinator</span><br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 
0px; padding-right: 0px;">
<span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: Garamond; font-
size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">3200 Woodland Ridge 
Boulevard <font size="1" color=“#000000”></a>|</font> Baton Rouge, LA 
70816<br> Phone: 225-753-3180 ext.1352 <font size="1" color=“#000000”>|
</font> Fax: 225-555-5555<br></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 
0px; padding-right: 0px;">
<span style="text-align: left; color: #000000; font-family: Garamond; font-
size: 10pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">E-Mail: 
mccraryj@ehsbr.org <font size="1" color=“#000000”>| 
</font>www.episcopalbr.org<br></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 
0px; padding-right: 0px;">
<img src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/e-mail-
signiture_orig.jpg" nosend="1" border="0" width="148" height=“50” 
alt=Episcopal School of Baton Rouge title=“Episcopal School of Baton Rouge”>
</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-left: 8px; padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 
0px; padding-right: 0px;">
<a href=https://www.facebook.com/episcopalbr/><img 
src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/1468419350.png" 
alt=Facebook style="width:28px;height:28px;”></a><a 
href=https://www.instagram.com/episcopalbr/><img 
src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/1468419163_1.png" 
alt=Instagram style="width:28px;height:28px;"><a 
href=https://www.instagram.com/episcopalbr/><img 
src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/1468419163_1.png" 
alt=Instagram style="width:28px;height:28px;"><a 
href=https://twitter.com/EpiscopalBR><img 
src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/1468419364.png" 
alt=Twitter style="width:28px;height:28px;"><a 
href=https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_YRWq4LXw4ON07XoKFhxpA><img 
src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/1468419371.png" 
alt=Youtube style="width:28px;height:28px;"><a 
href=https://plus.google.com/101907942367473945105/posts><img 
src="http://www.episcopalbr.org/uploads/2/9/5/7/29573303/1468419380.png" 
alt=Google+ style="width:28px;height:28px;">
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>

<style>
a {color: #000000;}
</style>

</html>
```

Comment: James, you're going to need to use jQuery, AJAX for this. I have not used Google Forms yet so I don't know what the API is like. But you're also going to need some authentication so the information isn't public.

It should also be noted that you shouldn't be using "inline CSS" you should use a style sheet and classes.

In short, it's a good effort but there's a lot to learn. If this is something you need quickly, you might have to hire a professional.

Comment: Banks for the info. Not worried about authentication since none of the data is private. It is already public facing. I'm going to investigate jQuery now. Thanks!